# Action with parameter returns 404 in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have this before action inside my controller

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'delete-property') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }
}
```

and this is the controller action

```
   //Property Delete ID
   public function actionDeleteProperty($id)
    {
      $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
      echo $id;
    }
```

This is the url manager

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:[\d]+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
        ],
    ],
```

When i visit `http://localhost/hotel/delete-property/60d75e5842777110b81711b3` i get `404`

Why am i getting the 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern for id parameter is `[\d]+`. `\d` matches any decimal digit, but your id is in hexadecimal so letters make it not match the `[\d]+` pattern. You can use `\w` instead, and change your rule for example like this:

```
'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:[\w]+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```